# If $a^6\mid b^6$, then does $a\mid b$?

Tags: number-theory

> If $a^6 \mid b^6$, where $a,b\in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$, then does $a\mid b$?

I was thinking of using the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic to show that $$a^6=\prod_{i}p_{i}^{6k_i}\quad\text{and}\quad b^6=\prod_{i}p_{i}^{6q_i}$$ And, since $6k_i\leq 6q_i$, $\forall i$, $k_i \leq q_i$ which implies $a\mid b$.

Is this correct?

Comment: You are right! I think it's the easiest way to see that.

Comment: Yes, this is a correct way to solve it.

Comment: Here is another cute way to solve it. Let $k=\frac{b^6}{a^6} \in \mathbb Z$. Then, $\frac{b}{a}$ is a rational root of $X^6-k \in \mathbb Z[X]$, and hence an integer root.